# How to sort a class member vector?

Tags: c++, sorting, vector

I'm working in a code that sorts a list with a key for each element, and I'm using the STL function sort. However the key function that I need must be a non-static function of a class, and the compilator refuses to accept that function. Any suggestions are apreciated.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

class Class {
    public:
        Class (int i): my_int(i) {}
        int f (int x) { return x % my_int; }
        bool key (int i1, int i2) { return f(i1) < f(i2); }
        void sort_v () { std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), this->key) }
    private:
        std::vector<int> v = {4,6,3,2};
        int my_int;
};

int main() {
    Class c(3);
    c.sort_v();
    return 0;
}
```

Note: A friend function can't be easily implemented because the arguments of key(int, int) are automaticly passed, and since f is not static we would have no way to pass 'this' class data.

Answer (score 3):

Just use lambda:

```
void sort_v () {
    std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), [this](auto a, auto b) { return key(a, b); });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can either use `std::bind`:

```
void sort_v () { 
    using std::placeholders;
    std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), std::bind( &Class:key, this, _1, _2 ) ); 
}
```

or use lambda:

```
void sort_v () { 
    std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), [this]( int x, int y ) { return key( x, y ); ); 
}
```

to make your method work.

Comment: @SergeyA OMG am I allowed to use `std::function` in 2019?

Comment: @Slava The problem with `std::function` is that it uses type erasure.  That is expensive and often prevents inlining.  `std::bind` might not return a `std::function`, but it isn't specified so we don't know without checking the assembly.  A lambda on the other hand is trivial to inline and if it is non-capturing it is typically a zero cost abstraction.  I have seen cases where `bind` is really needed, but this isn't one of them.

Comment: Do we get opinion police here which dictates what can or cannot be used?

Comment: @Slava `std::function` and `std::bind` are completely different use cases. std::function type-erases, and sometimes you have two (i.e. you are dealing with non-template callbacks). As for policing, we are, in regulator's parlance, SRO - self-regulatory organization. We pick solutions based on their feasibility and lambda would be a win over bind in any scenario I can imagine.

Comment: @NathanOliver where would you use `std::bind` (as opposed to lambda)? Also, even capturing lambda is all but guaranteed to perfectly inline in simple cases like this one. And even when it doesn't inline, there still would not be virtual call (unlike `std::function`)